# How to get the post vars from a form via user function

Tags: forms, typo3, typoscript

On a Typo3 website a form is integrated. The action should be routed to a typoscript user function.

This is what I tried so far:

The fluid form code (excerpt):

```
<form action="{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath: 'lib.mynlreg')}" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Ihre E-Mail-Adresse">
  <input type="submit" name="send" value="Jetzt registrieren" class="submit" />
</form>
```

The typoscript lib:

```
lib.mynlreg = USER_INT
lib.mynlreg {
   userFunc = Vendor\Extension\myClass->myFunction
}
```

And the class:

```
class myClass {

  public function myFunction($content, $conf) {
      $arguments = $this->request->getArguments();
      $formEmail = $arguments['email'];
      return '<div>' . $formEmail . '</div>';
  }

}
```

I expect to get the content of the form field "email", but after submitting the page throws an error. The question is, how do I get the post vars into the user function? Thank you for any help!

Comment: Have you tried  this $variables = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_GP('email');??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$this->request` is not available in a userFunc. As gautamsinh mori says, you should use `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_GP('email');`, however I'm not sure you understand what the `f:cObject` ViewHelper does.

With this code, your HTML before submitting the form will be:

```
<form action="<div></div>" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Ihre E-Mail-Adresse">
  <input type="submit" name="send" value="Jetzt registrieren" class="submit" />
</form>
```

Your HTML after submitting will be:

```
<form action="<div>filledInEmail</div>" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Ihre E-Mail-Adresse">
  <input type="submit" name="send" value="Jetzt registrieren" class="submit" />
</form>
```

I'd recommend making an extension for this, but if you really want/need to do it like this, I think what you're looking for is something like:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.mynlreg" />
<form action="{uri.page(addQueryString: 1)}" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Ihre E-Mail-Adresse">
  <input type="submit" name="send" value="Jetzt registrieren" class="submit" />
</form>
```

This will create the form with action to the current page (including any query string). You then have to change the userFunc to return an empty string if the form hasn't been submitted. Something like:

```
class myClass {
    public function myFunction($content, $conf) {
        $formEmail = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_GP('email');
        if (empty($formEmail)) {
            return '';
        }
        return '<div>' . $formEmail . '</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Rudy, many thanks for your help! My main problem is that I have to use a certain PHP script as action for the form. Since you shouldn't specify the PHP file directly as an action, I thought it would be best to define a user function. But I don't know that much about it yet and those were my first tests. Is this basically the right way or is there a better way?

Comment: If you're using TYPO3 9, you could see if you can use the `form` extension with a custom Finisher. I don't have any experience with it, but know it's possible and looks pretty easy: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/form/Concepts/FrontendRendering/Index.html#concepts-frontendrendering-codecomponents-customfinisherimplementations. If you're using an older TYPO3 version, you could probably use `powermail`. This also supports custom finishers: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/powermail/ForDevelopers/AddFinisherClasses/Index.html

Comment: I have tried it with a Powermail Finisher - the problem is that the email is always sent first, because (as I read in the description) the Finisher is always executed AFTER it is sent. Alternatively Powermail offers the possibility to use a DataProcessor, the data will be processed BEFORE sending, but an e-mail will still be sent afterwards. Do you know how to prevent the sending of e-mails so that only my function is actually executed? Thank you again for your help !!!!

Comment: I'm not that familiar with powermail, but if I understand the manual correctly you should be able to disable sending the email by setting `plugin.tx_powermail.settings.receiver.enable = 0` and `plugin.tx_powermail.settings.sender.enable = 0` in TypoScript.

Comment: I have now tried again how you suggested it at the beginning of your post and extended the PHP function according to my given PHP code - and that works! Thanks for your help!